# How can I get PyCharm to recognize a newer python interpreter through Conda?

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, python-3.9

I have been running using a python 3.6 conda environment in my PyCharm projects for a while but recently installed a python 3.9 version through conda. I cannot find it as an interpreter option in PyCharm, I am only able to use conda environments for 3.7 or 3.8. When I run the docked python terminal through the PyCharm IDE it actually runs the python 3.9 version but I can't make it a project interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the version of your *interpreter from the bottom right corner*, otherwise you will see the message to **No interpreter**, you can click on the Python version and follow these steps:

**Add Interpreter>>System Interpreter>>Click on ..>>your interpreter path.**

Its work for me at pycharm version 2021.1

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm an idiot but I'll leave this here in case there are future idiots in need. The python version had changed, it's just that my default interpreter was (somehow) named Python3.7 so I was assuming it wasn't working, but checking the python version

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

showed that I was in fact using python 3.9.